AWS CloudWatch Log filter for key words
I have logs being sent to AWS CloudWatch from ECS tasks that are running a Python script in a container. Every now and then, an Exception occurs where I'd like to get an error email for them.
I have a Lambda set up to send the email already. The problem currently is the log events aren't triggering the lambda.
I have the filter currently set to '?Exception ?Error ?Traceback' for the typical Python logs, but nothing is currently being captured that correctly sets off the alarm.
Am I doing something wrong?

can you provide an example, anonymised log message, please? With filter you mean a metric filter on the Log group?

a log message would help. @ChristianBanfi i think he means subscription filter.

An example log entry would be:
Traceback (most recent call last):
